# Work around for lack of Multichannel design (two-dimensional) bus support in Altium Designer

Tags: altium

So Altium Designer [still does not have support for multi-dimensional buses and repeat statements](https://bugcrunch.live.altium.com/#Idea/4603).  The repeat blocks can be used to do [some very cool things](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/166776/altium-repeated-sheets?rq=1), but the only work-around I've found is to brute force one of the levels of the design and [remove it's hierarchy](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/altium/complex-multi-channel-design-with-hierarchy-and-repeated-blocks/).

My design is similar to those in the links above.  I have a lower block of LED drivers with 4 LEDs per driver, and I'd like to repeat that many times in a higher-level channel block, likely something like 24 channels.  It looks like my only option right now is to flatten the LED driver schematics so they don't use repeat statements and buses.

Does anyone have a better way?  Is there a way to trick Altium into letting nested or multidimensional buses and repeat statements work?

EDIT: It appears that one of the issues where is the buses inside the repeat block give a duplicate net names error.  This is because the net names are not appended with the repeat naming convention the way rooms and components are (as specified in Project Options/ Multi-Channel).  I'm not sure why this is a problem for buses but not for regular nets, but it is.  If there's a way to overcome this issue, then it seems like it might be able to translate bus names inside the repeat block and achieve nested buses.  Maybe.  Does anyone know how to get buses to work inside repeat blocks?

Comment: Did you try using a signal harness? For me it solved a 3 level deep hierarchy with multiple repeating blocks (several radios, gpio expanders and more)

Comment: I have not tried a harness.  I'll give that a look...